# How do I properly detect and report that my CouchDB instance is down, when using the couch_client library?

Tags: node.js, couchdb

I'm using nodejs, with the couch_client library, and trying to connect to an instance of CouchDB which ain't there. As a result, node crashes giving me something along these lines as output:

```
node.js:116
        throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
        ^
Error: ECONNREFUSED, Connection refused
    at Client._onConnect (net.js:576:18)
    at IOWatcher.onWritable [as callback] (net.js:165:12)
```

I bet I'm making an obvious mistake somewhere - maybe someone with a fresh mind can point it out for me? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Just catch the exception.

```
try {
    go_ding({when:"there's stuff"});
} catch(e) {
    couldnt_connect();
    // Maybe setTimeout and retry, etc.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you could just query the couchdb node with a simple get request to the basic url. I doubt you need a CouchDB driver or framework for this?

CouchDB, the definitive guide about the [Core API](http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/api.html), Server API.

Comment: You mean that, instead of making one request through couch_client for the data I am looking for, I should now make two requests each time - one to check that the server is up and running, and a second to get the data?